# Rails 5 and asset-pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add a bootstrap theme into my rails 5 project. Everything goes well, except images and fonts. In my **app/assets/config/manifest.js** I have:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../fonts
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

And all my fonts and images are in **vendor/assets/fonts** and **vendor/assets/images**. So, what is wrong? Why I can't see the images and fonts?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you added bootstrap with the gem file, put your images in folder:

`app/assets/images`

Then use the code:

`<%= image_tag 'NAME.jpg', class: 'if any class', alt: 'description' %>`

It works find on `Rails 5.0.0.` For the fonts I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to open your command line tool and navigate to where your `manifest.js` file is.
From there, try to navigate to your `vendor` folder. 
Compare your findings to your current inputs and change your `manifest.js` accordingly ;-)